# Differents ways to evaluate the sum $\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\cdots}}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, nested-radicals

> Evaluate $$\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\cdots}}}}$$
> **My approach:**
> Let $$x=\sqrt{12+ \sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\cdots}}}$$
> so, we have that $$\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\cdots}}}}\iff \sqrt{12+x}=x \implies 12+x=x^{2} \iff (x+3)(x-4)=0$$
> So, the answer is $\boxed{4}$.

---

Is correct my solution?
Can you show other ways for to solve this problem?
Can you suggest me any  textbooks with similar problems?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Да, точно! Это правильно.

Comment: @JackLeGrüß Спасибо. Другой способ решить проблему?

Comment: The ramanujan way :$$\begin{align*}4=\sqrt{12+4}=\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+4}}&\\=\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+4}}}&\\...\text{so on}....................\end{align*}$$

Comment: Yes, but the ramanujan way also gives $$5=\sqrt{25}=\sqrt{12+13}$$ $$=\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+157}}$$ $$=\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+24637}}}$$ $$..\text{ so on }...$$ One must be careful with that reasoning

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore That was fantastic!

Comment: @АлександрПальма credits not to me! but to the great ramanujan!

Comment: @QC_QAOA  I think the trick behind it, is solve $x(x+1)=12$ so, we have the solution $x+1$, is it correct?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Great Ramanujan!

Comment: Its simply a comment that the "Ramanujan way" is not rigorous as presented. That is, I can make any value (larger than $4$ at least) look like $\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\cdots}}}$ if I use that reasoning

Comment: @QC_QAOA How can I distinguish the correct way to apply the Ramanujan way? Do I necessarily use convergence concepts?

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to [make it take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.  See [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.  The tag number theory is used for more advanced studies on properties of integers.  For number theoretic problems at an undergraduate level, the tag elementary number theory usually suffices.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 I understand. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Let $a_1=\sqrt{12}$ and $a_n=\sqrt{12+a_{n-1}}$. We must show that $a_n\to 4$. In order to do this, it is sufficient to show that

$1)\ \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\text{ exists}$

$2)\ \text{This limit is }4$

You have basically skipped step $1)$ and gone straight to step $2)$. To fill in the first step, first note that $0<a_n<4$ for all $n$. We proceed by induction:

$$0<a_1=\sqrt{12}<\sqrt{16}=4$$

$$0<\sqrt{12}\leq a_n=\sqrt{12+a_{n-1}}<\sqrt{12+4}=\sqrt{16}=4$$

Second, we may now show that $a_n$ is increasing. This is obvious as

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\sqrt{12+a_n}}{a_n}=\sqrt{\frac{12}{a_n^2}+\frac{1}{a_n}}$$

Since $a_n<4$, this becomes

$$\sqrt{\frac{12}{a_n}^2+\frac{1}{a_n}}>\sqrt{\frac{12}{16}+\frac{1}{4}}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{4}}=\sqrt{1}=1$$

Thus, $a_{n+1}>a_n$. Since we have already established that $a_n<4$ we may conclude that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$$

exists. This concludes step $1)$. As you have already proved step $2)$, we may conclude that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=4$$

The reason we may discard the $-3$ answer is that $0<a_n<4$ so $L\in[0,4]$.

---

EDIT: Edited as OP requested more resources for these types of infinite radicals. The best place to start (at least in my mind) is [Herschfeld's Convergence Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HerschfeldsConvergenceTheorem.html). The theorem states that

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \left[x_0+(x_1+(x_2+(\cdots +(x_k)^p)^p)^p)^p\right]$$

exists if and only if $(x_n)^{p^n}$ is bounded. We see that at each step, $x_n=12$. Since $12^{2^{-n}}$ is bounded, we may conclude that the series converges.

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1** - contraction mapping theorem.

Let $g : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be the map $x \mapsto \sqrt{x+12}$. For any $x, y \in [0,\infty)$, we have

$$\begin{align} & g(x) - g(y) = \sqrt{x+12} - \sqrt{y+12} = \frac{x - y}{\sqrt{x+12} + \sqrt{y+12}}\\
\implies & |g(x)-g(y)| \le \frac{|x-y|}{2\sqrt{12}}
\end{align}
$$
This means $g$ is a contraction mapping over $[0,\infty)$.

By [Contraction mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem), $g(x)$ have a unique fixed point over $[0,\infty)$. Furthermore, if one pick any $z \in [0,\infty)$ and construct a sequence $z_n$ by $$z_n = \begin{cases}z, &n = 0\\g(z) = \sqrt{z+12}, & n > 0\end{cases}$$
$z_n$ will converges to that fixed point.

Since $g(4) = 4$, that unique fixed point is $4$. By setting $z$ to $0$, we find

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
z_1 &=& \sqrt{12},\\
z_2 &=& \sqrt{12+\sqrt{12}},\\ 
z_3 &=& \sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12}}}\\
&\vdots&
\end{array}$$
converges to $4$.

**Method 2** - explicit bound.

Define $z_n$ as in method $1$ and let $y_n = 4 - z_n$ for $n \ge 1$.
Notice
$$y_{n+1} = 4 - z_{n+1} = 4 - \sqrt{12 + z_n}
= 4 - \sqrt{16-y_n}
= \frac{y_n}{4 + \sqrt{16-y_n}}\tag{*1}
$$
$y_{n+1}$ has same sign as $y_n$. Since $y_1 = 4 - \sqrt{12}> 0$, all $y_n$ are positive.
Notice $\sqrt{16-y_n} = \sqrt{12+z_n} \ge 12$, $(*1)$ implies

$$0 < y_{n+1} < \frac{y_n}{4+\sqrt{12}}$$

Replace $n$ by $1, 2, \ldots, m-1$ and combine the inequalities, we find for $m \ge 1$,

$$0 < y_m \le \frac{y_1}{(4+\sqrt{12})^{m-1}}\quad
\implies\quad 4 - \frac{4}{(4+\sqrt{12})^m}
\le z_m < 4$$
By squeezing,

$$\lim_{m\to\infty} z_m = \lim_{m\to\infty}
\underbrace{\sqrt{12 + \sqrt{12 + \sqrt{12 + \cdots}}}}_{m\text{ times}} = 4$$

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**
First see the comment of NinadMunshi immediately following this answer.  I have edited the answer accordingly.

---

Continuing Infinity_hunter's answer, and letting

$$x_n~ \text{denote}~ 
\sqrt{12 + \sqrt{12 +  \cdots  \text{n times} }}
$$

To show convergence, all that is necessary is to show that

- the sequence is bounded
- the sequence is strictly increasing.

Clearly, $0 < x_1 < 4.$  Assume that $0 < x_n < 4.$  Then

$$x_{(n+1)} = \sqrt{12 + x_n} < \sqrt{12 + 4} < 4$$

and

$$x_{(n+1)} = \sqrt{12 + x_n} > \sqrt{12 + 0} > 0.$$

Therefore,

$$0 < x_n < 4 \implies 0 < x_{(n+1)} < 4.$$

To show that the sequence is (therefore) strictly increasing:

Since

$$ 0 < x_n < 4$$

and

$$[(x_n)^2 - x_n - 12] = (x_n - 4)(x_n + 3)$$

I conclude that

$$[(x_n)^2 - x_n - 12] < 0 \implies (x_n)^2 < x_n + 12.$$

However, by the definition of the sequence

$$\left[x_{(n+1)}\right]^2 = x_n + 12.$$

Therefore

$$\left[x_{(n+1)}\right]^2 > (x_n)^2.$$

Therefore, since each element in the sequence is positive,

$$x_{(n+1)} > (x_n).$$

Therefore, the sequence is strictly increasing.

Comment: Strictly increasing is not correct, it depends what interval $x_n$ falls on. In fact your example shows the sequence decreases on some interval that contains $12$

Comment: @NinadMunshi (+1) also. Very good point.  Answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is correct. The other answers have addressed formality and rigour as a concern, but from the sound of your comments, you're more interested in the kind of problem more than the right answer, so I hope the following helps.

This kind of problem is an [infinitely nested radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Infinitely_nested_radicals). As far as I know, there's no other way as straightforward as recognizing the infinitely nested square root is just a quadratic in disguise. In fact, an infinitely nested cube root would be a cubic in disguise.

[Solution of Polynomial Equations with Nested Radicals](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.1948v2.pdf) on Arxiv actually derives a generic nested radical as a solution to a generalized quadratic equation, and dives deeper into different kinds of polynomials.

[On Infinitely Nested Radicals](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Emorrow/336_11/papers/brian.pdf) is a less crazier article from a magazine that discusses their convergence and what type of numbers could be represented by them.

[A Chronology of Continued Square Roots and Other Continued Compositions [...]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06139.pdf) on Arxiv is exactly what it sounds like. At a glance it's written pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show the sequence
$$
x_n = \sqrt{12 + \sqrt{12 +  \cdots  \text{n times} }}
$$ converges. Only then you can take $x = \sqrt{12 + \sqrt{12 +\cdots}} $ and continue to other steps.
It is easy to see that $x_n = \sqrt{12 + x_{n-1}}$ with $x_1 = \sqrt {12}$.
As answered by @user2661923 and @QC_QAOA the sequence $x_n$ is bounded. Here is an easy way of showing $x_n$ is strictly increasing. Observe that $x_1 < x_2$ and we assume that $x_{n-1} < x_n$. Then
$$x_{n+1} = \sqrt{12 +x_n} > \sqrt{12 + x_{n-1}} = x_n$$
which completes our inductive argument and we conclude that $x_n$ converges.

Observing that $x_n > 0$ for any $n$ we can conclude that $x \ge0$ by limit theorems. So we must have $x = 4$